# Android colored view containing textviews

Tags: android, view, viewgroup

Ive made a program which has a view in the top op the window (right under the title bar).
According to what is goin on in the program, the color of the view will change.

This works just fine.

Now my problem is: I want 2 textviews inside it, next to each other. So probably: View, Tablelayout, tablerow, textview, textview, tablerow end, tablelayout end, view end.

But this does not seem to work. It gave me the error "Java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo" and "View can not be cast to viewgroup".

Nowhere in the java code do i touch any of the new views in the xml code, the only java that touches that XML, is `TopView = (View)findViewById(R.id.TopView);` and `TopView.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN );` Topview is the outer view, and works perfectly without anything inside it.

This is the XML code

```
    ...
<View
        android:id="@+id/TopView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="20dp" 
        android:background="#8E8E8E" >



        <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/tableTrolo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <TableRow
                    android:id="@+id/TableRow000"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl1"
                        android:layout_width="120dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Vare :"
                        android:textSize="22dp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/lbl2"
                        android:layout_width="180dp"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="du grim" />

            </TableRow>
            </TableLayout>


    </View>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have `child-views` inside a `View`.

A `View` is **always** the leaf node in a layout hierarchy.

1.Re-write the 1st line of your xml-layout as:

> ```
> <LinearLayout
>     android:id="@+id/TopView"
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>     android:background="#8E8E8E">
> ```

2.Change corresponding Java code as below:

> ```
> TopView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.TopView);
> ```

Comment: I dont see the change in the XML you've written? 
Changing the view to a viewgroup, will i still be able to change the backgroundcolor of the view (that is now a viewgroup)? Or do i need to change the color of the tablelayout, inside the viewgroup?

Comment: Yes, ViewGroup has background that can be changed, the same way you change it for View

Comment: I've edited my answer. Yes, you will be able to change the background color of the `ViewGroup` after this change. Hope this helps.

Comment: Still gives a "Java.lang.runtimeexception". This time "android.view.inflateexception", "error inflating class viewgroup." on the XML line <ViewGroup

Comment: I mentioned `ViewGroup` to get the concept right regarding how `Views` and `ViewGroups`should be used. For you code I think any elementary layout should work fine. I have updated my answer to use `Linear Layout`. You can also change `android:layout_height="20dp"` to `android:layout_height="wrap_content"' and try.

Comment: So really, change the view, to a layout instead? I guess this makes sense, you can still decide the layouts size and color.. Dont have time to try it out right now, but im pretty sure this will work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You are placing multiple elements inside a `View` tag. `View`'s don't hold children Views, there's `ViewGroup` class for that. Use one of `FrameLayout`,`LinearLayout`,`RelativeLayout` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `View`. Change your `View` to `ViewGroup`. The difference between View and ViewGroup is that ViewGroup CAN contain other Views. If you want to put some TextViews and other things inside it, you should use `ViewGroup` or some kind of Layout, like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`.